# MySQL group small results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a few million lines of data.

Processing this data can be very hard for some of my applications. I want to groups small values as an "others" value.

Example:

```
date       val   count
2017-01-25 ua5    50
2017-01-25 ua6    49
2017-02-25 ua8    35
2017-02-25 ua3    20
2017-01-25 ua1     2
2017-01-25 ua2     2
2017-02-25 ua9     1
2017-02-25 ua7     1
2017-01-25 ua4     1
```

This woul be better:

```
date       val   count
2017-01-25 ua5    50
2017-01-25 ua6    49
2017-02-25 ua8    35
2017-02-25 ua3    20
2017-01-25 other   5
2017-02-25 other   2
```

The values should be grouped by date, since i am selecting data for a specific range.

Is this even possible with mysql?

Comment: Use a case expression to put small values together. GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming smaller values are less than `10` then you can do grouping with `case` expression  :

```
select date, (case when count <= 10 then 'other' else val end) as val, sum(count)
from table t
group by date, (case when count <= 10 then 'other' else val end);
```

Comment: Yup!, This is the solution! Thank you so much. WIll accept this as the correct answer in 6 minutes :-)